# How do i display Form1 Time to form2 label?

Tags: vb.net, forms

I've tried this code in form2: label1 as hour, label2 as min and label3 as sec

```
Label1.Text = Form1.Label9.Text
Label2.Text = Form1.Label8.Text
Label3.Text = Form1.Label7.Text
```

Comment: Could you put your form1 and form2 code?

Comment: Using the default instance of `Form1` will only work if you've opened it with that as well. If you've created an instance of `Form1` first you need to pass that specific instance to `Form2`, or implement some kind of property/notification system.

Comment: This question has been asked so many times before that I don't even know which answer to reference... Plutonix has a pretty good one here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46867327

Comment: There are Thousands of questions already here on this - just Google your title if you dont like the one @VisualVincent linked.  The problem with choosing one is finding one that uses default form instances which is a much more amateur way of using them.

Answer (score 0):

VB.Net is not like VB6 anymore, you can't just change elements on forms other than this/self. You need to look up access levels in VB.Net, the difference between "friend", "protected" and "public" and when to use them.

But to actually answer the question, try making an instance of Form2 while running Form1, e.g.

```
Sub someForm1Routine
     Dim myForm2 As New Form2
     Application.Run(myForm2)
```

Comment: i see, so what should i do?

Comment: Updated my answer, create an instance of Form2 on Form1. This should give access to elements of both.

Comment: You don't open forms with `Application.Run()`, you open forms with [**`Form.Show()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.show(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I have done this many times in VB.net and it works fine.

```
Public Class Form4
    Private Sub Form4_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Label1.Text = "Foo"
    End Sub

    Private Sub cmdCloseForm_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdCloseForm.Click
        Form5.Label1.Text = Label1.Text
        Form5.Show()
        Close()
  End Sub
End Class
```

If you have closed Form1, that could be a problem because the values in the Text property are not persisted.